.Net Rate limiting. Increasing number of partitions
How are partitions handled in .Net rate limiters, especially when those partitions are created by IP address (e.g. https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/advanced-rate-limiting-use-cases-in-dotnet#rate-limiting-users-by-ip-address)?
It seems that when partitions are created by IP/user identity (or any other data, the number of variations of which we do not control) etc., the number of partitions (and corresponding rate limiters) can grow uncontrollably and remains in memory forever. Am I missing some mechanism of controlling partition life span or something of the kind?
